# In excel, I have a cell that in dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm format, i want to extract date as a string

Tags: excel

I have a cell that has date time in the following format. dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm. Now i need to extract the date out of it as a string and append to it a different time. And i need the final result as a string. Whats the best way to do this.?

Comment: WHERE do you need the final result ? In VBA or in another cell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your date/time was in A1, your second time in A2 then
in A3

=TEXT(A1,"dd-mm-yyyy")&" " &TEXT(A2,"hh:mm")

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the result is requirde in VBA:

```
strFormatYouWant = "yyyymmdd"  'or any valid date format
strDt = format(range("a2"), strFormatYouWant)
```

Otherwise, see @brettdj's reply